# Paypal Mobile Payment Verification Failed in .Net error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I need to verify paypal payment done using mobile device but it always return 
**java.lang.NullPointerException** error

C# Code

```
// Get a reference to the config
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

// Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

var PayID = "PAY-6PU626847B294848Y6KEWXHY";

var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, PayID);
```

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, header information was missing

```
var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        if (apiContext.HTTPHeaders == null)
        {
            apiContext.HTTPHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            apiContext.HTTPHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            apiContext.HTTPHeaders.Add("Authorization", accessToken);
        }
```

Thank you